# Adding debug symbol for dll in gdb (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, mingw

I am trying to redo steps of a Linux 'hacking' tutorial in Windows.
In one step the program is debugged using GDB. 
The command `ptype` is used in order to the class definitions of the class `Player` which is located in a DLL called `GameLogic.dll`.
I try to mimic [this exact step](https://youtu.be/8wz2CM0483o?list=PLhixgUqwRTjzzBeFSHXrw9DnQtssdAwgG&t=519) and use `ptype` on GDB I installed for Windows using MINGW. However, I cannot see any definitions since no symbol file is loaded:

```
(gdb) ptype Player
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

A symbol file `GameLogic.pdb` is located inside the DLL directoy. It is provided intentionally to investigate the program's structure further. 
Yet, using the `file` command I cannot load it into the program:

```
(gdb) file "E:/xx/PwnAdventure3/Binaries/Win32      
/GameLogic.pdb"
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) y
"E:/xx/PwnAdventure3/Binaries/Win32      
/GameLogic.pdb": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

This error could be due to the different executable format used by Windows.
However, there are other methods which I found online while researching this issue:

```
add-symbol-file filename address
set debug-file-directory <directory>
```

I cannot figure out how I should use these in this particular case. Since in the examples they provide a `.o` file as filename. Even though I could provide the `.pdb` file I also need an address (I suppose it's the address at which the DLL is loaded?).
Defining a different directory via `set debug-file-directory <directory>` which contains the `.pdb` file does not work.

I also tried different debuggers like OllDBG, WINDBG, Visual Studio and IDA Pro. In Visual Studio I can see that the symbols where loaded but I cannot find any method to further dig into the disassembled file. Only in OllyDBG I can see that the methods which belong to the `Player` class, e.g., `Player::SetJumpState(bool)` are correctly depicted.
I also must admit that I don't have much experience with these tools.

Which steps are necessary in order to load the symbols for the DLL file in GDB additionally so that the ptype command works?
Is there another (better) method using one of the mentioned programs to recreate the `Player` class along with it's local variables?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately GDB does not support reading symbols from PDB files currently, even on Windows. WinDBG/Visual studio should work though.

Comment: Unless the program has DWARF style debugging information as well. MSVC and it's debuggers won't read that. I guess you can't win sometimes.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure if there's a way to get both in a binary. Maybe with LLVM/Clang?